# How to count how many times a value is repeated in an array using binary search?

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

I'm not able, through binary search, to count the number of times a number is repeated in a vector. Here's the code:

```
v = {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5}
elem = 2

n = len(v)
lef = 0
rig = n - 1

while lef <= rig:
   mid = (lef + rig) // 2
   if v[mid] == elem:
       aux=+1
       break
   elif elem < v[mid]:
       rig = mid - 1
       aux=+1
   else:
       lef = mid + 1
       aux=+1

if v[mid] == elem:
  print(mid)
else:
  print(-1)

print(aux)
```

As you can see, I put a variable named `aux` serving as a counter inside the `if` and `elif`, but the output is not as expected. In the code I put the printing of the position to make sure that the algorithm in the part of finding the index is working.

I also thought about using another loop inside the `while`, but it soon came to mind that it would make the algorithm more expensive, but would that be the only way? How could I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple idea: call binary search twice. That way you won't sacrifice the time complexity.

```py
v = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
elem = 2
n = len(v)

def find_lo():
    lef = 0
    rig = n - 1
    while lef <= rig:
        mid = (lef + rig) // 2
        if v[mid] == elem:
            if not mid:
                return mid
            if v[mid] != v[mid-1]:
                return mid
            rig = mid-1
        elif elem < v[mid]:
            rig = mid - 1
        else:
            lef = mid + 1
    
    return None
    
def find_right():
    lef = 0
    rig = n - 1
    while lef <= rig:
        mid = (lef + rig) // 2
        if v[mid] == elem:
            if mid >= n-1:
                return mid
            if v[mid] != v[mid+1]:
                return mid
            lef = mid+1
        elif elem < v[mid]:
            rig = mid - 1
        else:
            lef = mid + 1
    
    return None

print(find_lo())    # 2
print(find_right()) # 4
```

Note: the two methods can be refactored as a single function to reduce redundancy, this is just a simple demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use algorithm available in python's [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html), it is just:

```
import bisect
v = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
elem = 2
print(bisect.bisect_right(v, elem) - bisect.bisect_left(v, elem))
```

output:

```
3
```

Answer (score -1):

v = {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5} is a set, and a set cannot have duplicates

The duplicates are deleted because of the way you declared v, so you will no be able to count repetitions.

```
v = {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5}
print(v)

>>>{1,2,3,4,5}
```

You can use a list, and count the duplicates with Counter

```
from collections import Counter

v = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print(v)

_=[print(f"{element}: {copies} times") for element,copies in Counter(v).items()]
```

it outputs

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1: 2 times
2: 3 times
3: 1 times
4: 1 times
5: 1 times
```